# WCF and IIS: updating a service

Tags: .net, wcf

We are about to deploy wcf web services and are wondering if an update or bug fix is needed, does iis need to be stopped and restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can simply restart the application on which the service is running (i.e., if you edit web.config on the application, it will be restarted for you). The other apps on IIS will continue working normally.

Comment: Thanks. What if it is a shared service. Would that mean that anyone consumming that endpoint would have to have a restart? Or would the next transaction have the new 'code'.

Comment: I don't know about transactions, but I did a quick test (create new Wcf Service Application, add an <appSettings> value to web.config; replace the implementation of GetData with "Thread.Sleep(10000); return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];", and fired up the test client. While a call was pending I changed the value of MyKey on the app settings, and the result didn't reflect that, but on the next call it did. So the existing calls will complete, but the new app domain will be used for the next calls.